# A Python GUI generator

Tags: python

I've been working on my first python software and I'm almost done, I have to work on the GUI of it. But i haven't studied python GUI.

Is there any software like Photoshop that automatically converts my graphical designs in it into Python GUI codes ? like Tkinter?

Comment: I’m not an expert, so I’ll let one answer, but the best that my searching yields is PyQt with Qt Designer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have provided a command line interface with `argparse` *usually a good idea* then you can have a [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) GUI with 2 pip installs and 2 lines in your main python file.

This is thanks to [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey)!

On the command line run:

```
pip install wxPython Gooey
```

Then in your main file add an import and a decorator:

```
from gooey import Gooey

@Gooey     # <--- all it takes! :)
def main():
  parser = ArgumentParser(...)
```

Also there is [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to design your GUI with drag and drop.

I strongly recommend, once you have run `pip install wxPython` that you run `wxdemo` which will download and run the matching demo. It is a great source of reference and inspiration on the components available.

All of the above is cross platform, free & open source.

*Disclaimer - I am the original author of the `wxdemo` launcher but not of the demos themselves.*